# How to search for column name in range or column is null

Tags: sql

I have an query that I am writing where i have a table containing a list of ages, this column can have NULLS. I have been trying to get a result containing users ages 18+ and if the users age is NULL i would like that result as well. Here is a simplified version of what im trying to do below, and the results.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (Table.Column >= 18 OR Table.Column IS NULL)
```

-Returns users of all ages and nulls

```
SELECT * `FROM TABLE WHERE ((Table.Column >= 18) OR (Table.Column IS NULL))
```

-Returns users of all ages and nulls

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (Table.Column >= 18 NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 17)
```

-Returns only users 18+, does not return NULLS

```
SELECT * `FROM TABLE WHERE ((Table.Column >= 18)
```

-Returns only users 18+, does not return NULLS

Any insight to what may be happening would be a blessing. This is part of a 1300 line query and this is the best i am able to simplify it. I may need you to keep in mind there may be other things going on which im un-able to explain and maybe a hacky work around is in order.

To go into further details, in psuedo code the entire query is as below.

```
      SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB,
        CASE
        WHEN (Condition 1),
        WHEN (Condition 2)
    ELSE 'N/A' END AS [Complete],
        CASE
        WHEN (Condition 1),
        WHEN (Condition 2)
    ELSE Column END AS [Column],
    ColumnC, ColumnD
    FROM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table A on A.Column = B.Column
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table C on A.Column = B.Column
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table D on A.Column = C.Column
WHERE (
Condition1,
and Condition2,
and (Table.Column >= 18 OR Table.Column IS NULL)
)UNION
SELECT
MAX([column]) AS [column],
MAX([MyColumn] AS [My Column],
FROM (
SELECT 
column],
MyColumn,
CASE
WHEN (Condition 1),
WHEN (Condition 2)
else 'N/A' end as [Complete]
CASE
WHEN (Condition 1),
WHEN (Condition 2)
ELSE Column END AS [Column],
Column3
WHERE (Condition1)
AND Condition2
)
and (Table.Column >= 18 OR Table.Column IS NULL)
GROUP BY [ColumnName]
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Comment: The column that you named 'Column' is of type NUMBER I suppose?

Comment: Why don't you just use COALESCE or IS NULL depending on what dbms.

SQLServer....
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COALESCE(Table.Column, 18) >= 18

Will get you the 18+s and NULL.
IF you want to exclude the nulls.....
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COALESCE(Table.Column, 17) >= 18

Comment: Is there a way of saying WHERE Table.Column IS NOT NULL THEN Table.Column must be >= 18    ?

Comment: I am getting confused?
You could use a CASE statement.

WHEN Column IS NOT NULL THEN 18 ELSE 17 END

But why store an age?

Comment: it was a smallint type which ive converted to varchar. I've tried using COALESCE and I get criteria that is NULL or 18+ but I am getting more results than i should, give me a moment, let me see if i can elaborate more on my query on stack

Comment: If its's a varchar, then you need to cast it to an int in your where clause.

Comment: Something else in your query is returning the extra rows. Either of the first two answers should get you what you are after.

Comment: Why would you convert a number to a varchar and then use an inequality on it? You would get the results you are after if that was stored as a number. Otherwise you are doing a lexicographical ordering for your inequality which may give you some screwy results.

Comment: To those proposing the coalesce in the where, [please stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Comment: @JohnHC that is completely RDBMS dependant. For instance, the parsing engine in Teradata will rewrite a COALESCE in a WHERE statement as an `OR` just as OP has here in option 1 making the query sargable. If you don't know how your RDBMS's parsing engine and optimizer are going to behave with your query, then I agree, avoiding coalesce is a sound tactic.

Comment: @JNevill That's a feature of that DBMS, none tagged here so assume ANSI/raw, sargability is relevant.

Comment: I think the issue it it goes Table Union, Table Union, Table Union, Can i wrap this whole thing in some sort of statement and say where column >=18 and column is not null?

Answer (score 0):

For my case I had to put the three tables which were being union together in 3 different sub queries, from there I put my where clause

```
SELECT A.* FROM (
Select * FROM TABLE1
) A
WHERE (A.ColumnOne >= 18 OR ColumnOne IS NULL)
UNION
SELECT B.* FROM (
Select * FROM TABLE2
) B
WHERE (B.ColumnOne >= 18 OR ColumnOne IS NULL)
UNION
SELECT C.* FROM (
Select * FROM TABLE2
) C
WHERE (C.ColumnOne >= 18 OR ColumnOne IS NULL)
```